How can I declare a template that takes templated callable and use that callable?
I've got a few classes that require heap allocation. There may be a lot of the same types of objects, simple example:
struct Node;
struct GenerationStrategy
{
    virtual void Generate(const Node& node) const = 0;
};

struct GenerationOneStrategy : GenerationStrategy
{
    void Generate(const Node& node) const override;
};
struct GenerationTwoStrategy : GenerationStrategy
{
    void Generate(const Node& node) const override;
};
struct GenerationThreeStrategy : GenerationStrategy
{
    GenerationThreeStrategy(std::string_view sv)
     : sv(sv) {}

    void Generate(const Node& node) const override;
private:
    std::string_view sv;
};

struct Node
{
    std::shared_ptr<GenerationStrategy> genStrat;
};

std::vector<Node> nodes;

for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
{
    Node& node = nodes.emplace_back();
    node.genStrat = std::shared_ptr<GenerationOneStrategy>();
}
for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
{
    Node& node = nodes.emplace_back();
    node.genStrat = std::shared_ptr<GenerationTwoStrategy>();
}
for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
{
    Node& node = nodes.emplace_back();
    node.genStrat = std::shared_ptr<GenerationThreeStrategy>("Test");
}

There are also other strategies, not necessarily related to "Generation", but for the following example, instead of creating 150 objects, I thought of making a cacher class
inline void hash_combine(std::size_t& seed) { }

template <typename T, typename... Rest>
inline void hash_combine(std::size_t& seed, const T& v, Rest... rest) {
    std::hash<T> hasher;
    seed ^= hasher(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
    hash_combine(seed, rest...);
}

template<typename BaseStrategy>
struct StrategyCacher
{
    template<typename ConcreteStrategy, typename ... Args> 
        requires std::is_base_of_v<BaseStrategy, ConcreteStrategy> && std::constructible_from<ConcreteStrategy, Args...>
    [[nodiscard]] std::shared_ptr<ConcreteStrategy> CreateStrategy(Args&& ... args)
    {
        std::size_t key = 0;
        hash_combine(key, std::type_index(typeid(ConcreteStrategy)), args...);

        if (cache.contains(key)) {
            return std::static_pointer_cast<ConcreteStrategy>(cache.at(key));
        }

        auto strategy = std::make_shared<ConcreteStrategy>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        cache[key] = strategy;
        return strategy;
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::shared_ptr<BaseStrategy>> cache;
};

using GenerationStrategyCache = StrategyCacher<GenerationStrategy>;

This has worked fine for some time, but now I need more flexible way to generate key value.
I thought of defining a template parameter in StrategyCacher this way:
template<typename BaseStrategy, std::invocable KeyGen>
    requires std::same_as<std::invoke_result_t<KeyGen>, std::size_t>
struct StrategyCacher
{
    template<typename ConcreteStrategy, typename ... Args> 
        requires std::is_base_of_v<BaseStrategy, ConcreteStrategy> && std::constructible_from<ConcreteStrategy, Args...>
    [[nodiscard]] std::shared_ptr<ConcreteStrategy> CreateStrategy(Args&& ... args)
    {
        const std::size_t key = KeyGen()<ConcreteStrategy>(args...);

        if (cache.contains(key)) {
            return std::static_pointer_cast<ConcreteStrategy>(cache.at(key));
        }

        auto strategy = std::make_shared<ConcreteStrategy>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        cache[key] = strategy;
        return strategy;
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::shared_ptr<BaseStrategy>> cache;
};

using TypedKeyGen = decltype([]<typename T, typename ... Args>(Args&& ... args) -> std::size_t {
    std::size_t key = 0;
    hash_combine(key, std::type_index(typeid(T)), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return key;
});

using GenerationStrategyCache = StrategyCacher<GenerationStrategy, TypedKeyGen>;


but this code will not compile, because std::invocable KeyGen requires that KeyGen must be invocable without any arguments but TypedKeyGen requires at least one argument (a type T and variadic arguments Args...) to be used. Not saying that KeyGen()<ConcreteStrategy>(args...); is also wrong...
My next step was to move std::invocable into CreateStrategy function
template<typename BaseStrategy, typename KeyGen> //typename was std::invocable
struct StrategyCacher
{
    template<typename ConcreteStrategy, typename ... Args> 
        requires 
    (std::is_base_of_v<BaseStrategy, ConcreteStrategy> && std::constructible_from<ConcreteStrategy, Args...>) 
    && //added these requirements
    (std::invocable<KeyGen, Args...> && std::same_as<std::invoke_result_t<KeyGen>, std::size_t>)
    [[nodiscard]] std::shared_ptr<ConcreteStrategy> CreateStrategy(Args&& ... args)
    {
        const std::size_t key = KeyGen()<ConcreteStrategy>(args...);

        if (cache.contains(key)) {
            return std::static_pointer_cast<ConcreteStrategy>(cache.at(key));
        }

        auto strategy = std::make_shared<ConcreteStrategy>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        cache[key] = strategy;
        return strategy;
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::shared_ptr<BaseStrategy>> cache;
};

the requires part looks bad, but whatever for now, at least the previous error is gone.
Now there are problems with this syntax - KeyGen()<ConcreteStrategy>(args...);
error C2065: 'ConcreteStrategy': undeclared identifier
error C2760: syntax error: '...' was unexpected here; expected ')'
error C3878: syntax error: unexpected token ')' following 'simple_declaration'
message : error recovery skipped: ')'

I ended up having this
const std::size_t key = KeyGen{}.template operator()<ConcreteStrategy>(args...);
Is there a cleaner/shorter way to do this?
Now that KeyGen invocation works there is a problem with the requires part:
template<typename ConcreteStrategy, typename ... Args> 
        requires 
    (std::is_base_of_v<BaseStrategy, ConcreteStrategy> && std::constructible_from<ConcreteStrategy, Args...>) 
    && //!!! issues
    (std::invocable<KeyGen, Args...> && std::same_as<std::invoke_result_t<KeyGen>, std::size_t>)
    [[nodiscard]] std::shared_ptr<ConcreteStrategy> CreateStrategy(Args&& ... args)
    {
        const std::size_t key = KeyGen{}.template operator()<ConcreteStrategy>(args...);

        if (cache.contains(key)) {
            return std::static_pointer_cast<ConcreteStrategy>(cache.at(key));
        }

        auto strategy = std::make_shared<ConcreteStrategy>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        cache[key] = strategy;
        return strategy;
    }

when I do
using TypedKeyGen = decltype([]<typename T, typename ... Args>(Args&& ... args) -> std::size_t {
    std::size_t key = 0;
    hash_combine(key, std::type_index(typeid(T)), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return key;
});

using GenerationStrategyCache = StrategyCacher<GenerationStrategy, TypedKeyGen>;
GenerationStrategyCache genStratCache;

std::vector<Node> nodes;

for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
{
    Node& node = nodes.emplace_back();
    node.genStrat = genStratCache.CreateStrategy<GenerationOneStrategy>();
}
for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
{
    Node& node = nodes.emplace_back();
    node.genStrat = genStratCache.CreateStrategy<GenerationTwoStrategy>();
}
for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
{
    Node& node = nodes.emplace_back();
    node.genStrat = genStratCache.CreateStrategy<GenerationThreeStrategy>("Test");
}

I get tones of these errors:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   C2672   'StrategyCacher<GenerationStrategy,TypedKeyGen>::CreateStrategy': no matching overloaded function found

and when I click on them my IDE routes me to the node.genStrat = genStratCache.CreateStrategy
One possible "fix" is to remove constraints related to the KeyGen in CreateStrategy function.
I want some kind of requirement that KeyGen is a callable that returns a std::size_t. How can I do this?
Let's assume that there is no way to have that kind of constraint and let's just remove these requirements from CreateStrategy function, now it looks like this:
template<typename ConcreteStrategy, typename ... Args> 
        requires std::is_base_of_v<BaseStrategy, ConcreteStrategy> && std::constructible_from<ConcreteStrategy, Args...>
    [[nodiscard]] std::shared_ptr<ConcreteStrategy> CreateStrategy(Args&& ... args)
    {
        const std::size_t key = KeyGen{}.template operator()<ConcreteStrategy>(args...);

        if (cache.contains(key)) {
            return std::static_pointer_cast<ConcreteStrategy>(cache.at(key));
        }

        auto strategy = std::make_shared<ConcreteStrategy>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        cache[key] = strategy;
        return strategy;
    }

Now I can finally compile and run the application, but when I close the app I get the runtime error XD (AGAIN!!!). It's most probably related to the destruction of these objects (or their dependencies like std::string_view)
I don't know, I feel like it's too hard. I have no idea how to fix it. I thought that maybe std::forward<Args>(args)... in TypedKeyGen is the problem, but it's not.
Summarizing:

Is there a clearer way to do this: const std::size_t key = KeyGen{}.template operator()<ConcreteStrategy>(args...);?
Can I add constraints to KeyGen function?
What causes the problem on the screenshot above and how can I fix it?
What can I do better? Maybe I do everything wrong and it can be as flexible as I want but much simpler



This would be better split up into several questions... The crash looks unrelated to all this, use your ASAN or a similar tool to debug it.

Because you need that explicit template argument, you can't use std::invocable,std::invoke,std::invoke_result_t and others. I'd use decltype instead of the latter. Or alternatively, pass an empty templated struct (tag in my example): KeyGen{}(tag<ConcreteStrategy>{}, args...), this lets you use invoke.

I think the crash is related to the KeyGen, because the first CreateStrategy function works fine and it uses the same code to generate the key. It's actually the most important thing to me because I can live without constraining the KeyGen and calling it this "long" way. I don't even know how to debug it, the call stack shows some garbage stuff. I think it's an easy error to fix just by looking at the code, but I'd have to know what to look for.

Also I don't quite get use decltype instead of the latter. Or alternatively, pass an empty templated struct (tag in my example): KeyGen{}(tag<ConcreteStrategy>{}, args...). Could you rephrase it?
